# How to use a deque of tuples (node, val) in python?

Tags: python, graph, tuples, breadth-first-search, deque

I've been running into this error when doing a BFS of a graph in python.
https://leetcode.com/problems/all-nodes-distance-k-in-binary-tree/
"cannot unpack non-iterable treeNode object" occurs when I try to unpack a tuple in my deque, specifically this line:

node, dist = q.popleft()

```
def distanceK(self, root: TreeNode, target: TreeNode, k: int) -> List[int]:
        graph = defaultdict(list) 
        self.buildGraph(root, None, graph)
        
        visited = set()
        q = deque((target, 0))
        ret = [] 
        while q:
            node, dist = q.popleft()
            if node in visited:
                continue
                
            visited.add(node)
            if dist == k:
                ret.append(node.val)
            elif dist < k:
                for child in graph[node]:
                    q.append((child, dist+1))
                    
        return ret

        
    def buildGraph(self, node, parent, graph):
        if not node:
            return
        
        if parent is not None:
            graph[node].append(parent)
            
        if node.left is not None:
            graph[node].append(node.left)
            self.buildGraph(node.left, node, graph)
        
        if node.right is not None:
            graph[node].append(node.right)
            self.buildGraph(node.right, node, graph)
```

Fixed this issue using a pretty naive method (Below). Does anyone know a better way of going about this?

```
def distanceK(self, root: TreeNode, target: TreeNode, k: int) -> List[int]:
        graph = defaultdict(list) 
        self.buildGraph(root, None, graph)
        
        visited = set()
        **q = deque()
        q.append((target,0))**
        ret = [] 
        while q:
            node, dist = q.popleft()
            if node in visited:
                continue
                
            visited.add(node)
            if dist == k:
                ret.append(node.val)
            elif dist < k:
                for child in graph[node]:
                    q.append((child, dist+1))      
        return ret
```

Comment: The constructor for `deque` expects an iterable containing the items, not the item itself. It would work if you pass the tuple in a list like so `q = deque([(target, 0)])`. But your second approach is perfectly fine, because that is what the constructor is doing internally as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: In your original code, `deque((target, 0))` adds `target` and `0` as two items in the deque, rather than a single tuple item. This is why it can't unpack properly, the first `popleft()` will return just `target` and not a tuple.

Comment: @shriakhilc ah, simple yet i missed in docs. Thanks for clearing up

Comment: So you won't be confused in the future, the constructors for `list`, `tuple`, and `deque` all work the same.  They take one argument which is iterable containing all the values.